# PHP regex extract date

Tags: php, regex, string

i have `$date` variable `2009-04-29` which is `Y-m-d`

anybody can give idea how to extract into `$d`, `$m`, `$y` using simplest method as possible?
regex is preferable. 
any more suggestion with simple method will be chosen. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `explode` function

```
list ( $y, $m , $d ) = explode( '-' , $date ) ;
```

Refer following link for more information

[Click Here](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 3):

You could easily avoid regex by using

```
$y = substr($date, 0,4);
$m = substr($date, 5,2);
$d = substr($date, -2);
```

**Edit:** If you really want regex, you will have one =)

Try

```
preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/',  $date, $matches)
$y = $matches[1];
$m = $matches[2];
$d = $matches[3];
```

(I do not know if the backslashes in the expression need to be escaped, sorry)

Comment: remember: simplest method will be selected but, regex is preferable. :) i want to explore more on regex.

Comment: can we use list to simplify the code?

Comment: @apsi17: Dunno. Just try `preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/',  $date, list(, $y, $m, $d))` and report back. I have no php interpreter available to me at the moment.

Comment: its not work. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '=' `